# Unix: grep and ls

Tags: unix, grep, ls

I need to find a file in my current directory with the following restrictions: are at least two characters long and don't have the following letters anywhere in the first two characters: a,b,c,f,h,x,y,z.

I tried

```
$ ls | egrep '[[:alpha:]]{2,}' | grep -v '[abcfhxyz]'
```

but it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?:

```
$ ls [^abcfhxyz][^abcfhxyz]*
```

Comment: wait how does that work tho. when you have : "[^abcfhxyz][^abcfhxyz]*" doesn't that mean list only with those letter in it?

Comment: `[^...]` means _not the bracketed chars_.

Comment: theres something new, thank you. I've got an exam in 2 days

Comment: how would you do this one:  end in .ex with an optional c at the end

Comment: `ls *.{exc,ex}` or `ls |grep \.exc*$`

Comment: Or `ls *.ex{,c}`

Comment: Notice that Bash recognizes both `[^abc]` and `[!abc]` for negated bracket expressions, but POSIX only knows `[!abc]`.